# Modern DDR4 memory access latency system analysis

Tags: system, dram, system-on-chip, ddr4

[image]

The memory access latency for the Intel Core i7-11800H (source: [chipsandcheese](https://chipsandcheese.com/memory-latency-data/), cpu latency for Intel Core i7-11800H), using DDR4-3200, reveals specific timings: 1 ns for L1, 3 ns for L2, and 13 ns for L3 caches. When considering an open page, the CL (CAS latency) for DDR4-3200 is 15 ns. The cumulative latency till L3 is about 17 ns (1+3+13) and the open row access Tcl is 15 ns, but the overall memory latency depicted on the graph is approximately 110 ns. To account for this disparity, it's essential to factor in memory controller elements such as queue latency, scheduling, and bus latency. Could someone elucidate the breakdown of this 100+ ns of latency? Is there any aspect overlooked in this system analysis?

Comment: CAS latency is not relevant here - L3 cache is much bigger than the amount of data in an open RAM page. Ram page is KB size, L3 is MB. Thus you have to take the zoo of secondaries and tertiaries into account for RAM timing.

Comment: Hi there! Can you add more to that source, either URL if it's online, or a full description: Publication, writer, page etc?

Comment: @TurboJ But whenever there is a miss in L3 cache, request will be sent to memory controller and then dram to get that cache-line right ? Isn't what we are seeing in the graph beyond 16ns is DRAM access latency ?

Comment: Yes, but it will almost always need to access data in another row - and row changes take a noteworthy processing time inside the DDR-4 chips. That is why I mentioned the secondary and tertiary timings that will come into play here...

Comment: Thanks @TurboJ! Is there any way to figure out the average controller delay (queueing + scheduling ) and bus delays ?